# Avoiding duplicate data in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

How do I ensure that there is no 'key' duplication in every document. Since if every document will tend to have repeated 'key' the size of the overall collection is going to increase considerably. If I am using a cloud service like MMS for backup it will definitely prove expensive with such an approach. It costs 1$ per GB. According to estimates the duplicating keys will push up costs by 14% for cloud based MMS.

Note - I am not talking here about duplication of data caused due to embedding of documents.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by "key duplication"?

Comment: I mean(belong to the same collection) Doc1{a:1,b:2,c:3} and Doc2{a:12,b:22,c:33} ; the keys 'a','b', and 'c' are getting duplicated in every document.

Comment: You could use a single field that contains an array of an arbitrary number of values: `{d: [12, 22, 33]}`.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Maybe you can explain *why* you are concerned about it - are you worried you don't have enough disk space?  RAM?  Something else?  I'm not sure what you mean by "loose" schema - you don't get to specify to MongoDB what schema you will use, you just store documents that are self-describing of their schema.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loose schema but the key names will always be duplicated. This is a know 'issue' with MongoDB. There's a bug report here: [SERVER-863 Tokenize the field names](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-863).

Comment: Yes but my concern is keys getting duplicated , is there any way to prevent it?

Comment: Not as you describe it above. If you insert a key named `a` in `Doc1` and `Doc2` they will both take up storage space.